# Get-Adgroupmember exported to single row

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have an application that reads a text file for license assignment and currently is manually managed.

the format consists of a single row for each AD Group, The row starts to the word "Group", followed by the AD Group name and then with the users SAMAccountName and all members in a single row...
there is also some static information that does not change at the bottom of the file...

Group ADGroupName1 usersamaccountname1 usersamaccountname2 usersamaccountname3
Group ADGroupName2 usersamaccountname1 usersamaccountname2 usersamaccountname3
Group ADGroupName3 usersamaccountname1 usersamaccountname2 usersamaccountname3

Include this text as static
Include this text also
Include this text as well

##########################

found this base script on another post...

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'humdrives'" |
ForEach-Object {
$Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive
[PSCustomObject]@{
StaticV1 = "Group"
Group = $_.Name
Members = $Members.sAMAccountName
}
}
```

StaticV1    Group        Members

---

Group       ADGroupName1 {Sam1, Sam2, Sam3, Sam4...}

and it is really close, except I am not able to get past the truncated output, nor have I been able to get the data exported correctly text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the `-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join) to produce the desired string:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like 'humdrives'" |ForEach-Object {
    $Members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive
    # drop all values into array subexpression, then -join 
    @(
        "Group"
        $_.Name
        $Members.sAMAccountName
    ) -join ' '
} |Set-Content -Path export.txt
```

You can then append additional content to the file with the [`Add-Content` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/add-content):

```
@'

Include this text as static
Include this text also
Include this text as well

##########################
'@ |Add-Content -Path export.txt
```

Comment: That works great, how about getting static text along the bottom... after final line, skip 3 then...                                                                                                                              Include this text as static
Include this text also
Include this text as well

Comment: @DuhMan Use `Add-Content` to append additional text, I've updated the answer with an example :)

Comment: is there anyway to make the samaccountname in output to the CSV file lowercase... we have users that have Upper case names "First.Last"... and I need the csv to be "first.last"...

Comment: `$Members.sAMAccountName |% ToLower`